# SpriteKit game fps dropping after only a few nodes?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am making a game that has several balls bouncing around the screen, and the player can add walls that contain the areas in which the balls can bounce. for testing I have four balls, and I can separate each ball into its own bounds with 3 walls this works fine, no change in fps. the problem occurs when I add more walls, which will then cause unreachable areas to be covered by a black sprite node this node has no physics. after only getting 2 black nodes the fps drops to around 30. what could be causing this?

here is a picture to show what i mean:

[image]

the grey lines are walls and the black areas are unreachable areas

Comment: What **is** causing this is the Simulator. Test performance only on a device, Simulator performance is not representative of a real device. Not even close.

Comment: There's no need to speculate when you can measure.  Run the app for profiling and select the time profiler.  You can poke around in the time profiler and figure out which paths are taking the most time.  @LearnCocos2D is right that you have to run on the device to get a good sense of the performance on the device, but there's no reason you can't profile it on the simulator to understand why it's slow *in the simulator*.

Comment: It's slow in the simulator because it's a software renderer. It suffices to add a fullscreen background image to have fps drop below 60 fps even on the fastest Macs.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D correct answer.  This is covered in a similar question

Comment: Ok this makes sense, I cannot test on my phone, so is there a way to prove it is just the simulator? or do i just need to trust that it is?